# 'Failed to parse JSON: Closing quote expected in string' error while loading firebase backup into bigquery

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-bigquery

I am trying to load Firebase Realtime DB backup in json.gz(744 MB in size and 5 GB after unzip) from cloud storage into bigquery.
I have tried through both bigquery UI and python client but i'm getting this below mentioned error:

**Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: Closing quote expected in string; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value**

Since, this is a firebase daily backup, I am unsure that what would be incorrect with the data?

Here is the Python(2.7.15) code which is used to load the data:

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
credential_path = "path to credentials .json file"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'my_new_dataset'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
uri = 'gs://URI-PATH'
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    dataset_ref.table('hit_snapshot_table'),
    job_config=job_config)  # API request

assert load_job.job_type == 'load'

load_job.result()
```

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like submitting a bug report with the Firebase team would be a good idea.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks for the response. When I asked this issue with the Firebase support, they redirected me towards the bigquery. I'll raise a bug with Firebase today